# Writing a SQL query over a given set of values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to write a plsql query that allows me to query a set of known values that are not stored in a table.
Say those known values are the following strings:

- abc
- def
- ghi
- jkl

I would like to achieve something like the following:

```
select * from [fill-in-the-blank] myvalues 
where not myvalues in 
(
    select id from dbtable
)
```

..where I am trying to ascertain which of those know values are not in a database table.

**Constraints**

- This is pl/sql (oracle)
- This solution must run from within Oracle PL/SQL Developer
- I only have read access to the schema so I cannot create temporary tables.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a Common Table Expression (CTE) to accomplish this:

```
with cte as (
    select 'abc' as id from dual
    union all
    select 'def' from dual
    union all
    select 'ghi' from dual
    union all
    select 'jkl' from dual
)
select * 
from cte
where not id in 
(
    select id from dbtable
)
```

In fact, you may not even really need the CTE at all (though I find it aids readability):

```
select * 
from (
    select 'abc' as id from dual
    union all
    select 'def' from dual
    union all
    select 'ghi' from dual
    union all
    select 'jkl' from dual
)
where not id in 
(
    select id from dbtable
)
```

Comment: What is that `myvalues` ? When I run the first example I get `ORA-00904: "MYVALUES": invalid identifier`.

Comment: That's what happens when you copy and paste from the question without properly correcting it. ;-) Corrected - cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Old thread I know, but nobody mentioned

```
select * from table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('abc','def','ghi','jkl'));
```

You don't have to use `sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll`, of course. Available collection types can be listed using:

```
select c.owner, c.type_name, c.elem_type_name, c.length
from   all_coll_types c
where  c.coll_type = 'TABLE'
and    c.elem_type_name = 'VARCHAR2'
order by 1,2;
```